# Eagerly fetch multiple collection: differences between QueryOver and Query

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I have the classic situation Orders/OrderLines.
I wanted to fetch some orders and eagerly load the orderslines with an outer join.
I have noticed that if I use QueryOver:

```
var orders2 = session.QueryOver<Domain.Order>()
   .Where(x => x.Company == "HBP00").And(x => x.Number == "VI11001680")
   .Fetch(x => x.OrderLines).Eager
   .List();
```

I get a cartesian product.
**orders2** contains 11 rows even if there's just one order, but infact it has got 11 orderlines.
If I use Query:

```
var orders1 = session.Query<Domain.Order>()
    .Where(x => x.Company == "HBP00" && x.Number == "VI11001680")
    .Fetch(x => x.OrderLines)
    .ToList();
```

everything works properly.
The funny thing is I've analyzed the query and they're identical.
Is there anything I have to know not to get a cartesian product eagerly loading a collection with `QueryOver`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution reading [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/05/28/nhibernate-pitfalls-bags-and-join.aspx).

Apparently, you need `.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)` with CreateQuery, CreateCriteria or QueryOver but you do not need it with Query.

Here's how I fixed it:

```
var orders2 = session.QueryOver<Domain.Order>()
   .Where(x => x.Company == "HBP00").And(x => x.Number == "VI11001680")
   .Fetch(x => x.OrderLines).Eager
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
   .List();
```